# The collection has not been initialized - SharePoint Online - Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I'm wondering if someone can help. So I am trying to get a list of users from a SharePoint Online site using Powershell but get the following message.

`The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.`

My Code:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

$sourceUrl="https://site.sharepoint.com"
$UserName="user@domain"
$Password="********"
$SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

#$SPCredentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $UserName,$SecurePassword
#Connect-PnPOnline -Url $sourceUrl -Credentials $SPCredentials

$sourceCtx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($sourceUrl)
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
$sourceCtx.Credentials = $credentials

$sourceWeb=$sourceCtx.Web  
$sourceCtx.Load($sourceWeb)   
$sourceUsers=$sourceWeb.SiteUsers
$sourceCtx.Load($sourceUsers)

#Iterate through source site users
foreach($user in $sourceUsers)
{
    Write-Host $user.Email
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing following line after the `sourceCtx.Load`

> sourceCtx.executeQuery()

Comment: Thanks but when I add sourceCtx.executeQuery() after the last sourceCtx.Load I get the following error.

`Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a 
send."`